# Checking for unique index violation with bookshelfjs

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

In mongodb it's as easy as setting index: { unique: true } on the schema/ attribute/property/field. In bookshelf you can specify a unique index using knex. However how do you check to for whether or not there was a unique key violation? For instance if I setup username, email as unique keys, and someone creates a new record with the same username and email, it should throw an error. In Mongo this is as simple as checking for err.code 11000.

I could query the database and check to see if a record exists, but I'd rather NOT have to do two queries. (the check for a preexisting user and the insert).

Answer (score 0):

> For instance if I setup username, email as unique keys, and someone creates a new record with the same username and email, it should throw an error. In Mongo this is as simple as checking for err.code 11000.

It's the same principle with PostgreSQL. You're looking for `SQLSTATE` `23505`, which is `unique_violation`.

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43827704/398670) since the documentation for bookshelf.js is notably lacking mention of this. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1800) you're looking for an `sqlState` attribute in the error dictionary, assuming the MySQL and PostgreSQL drivers for node behave the same.

Presumably that's `err.sqlstate`?

It looks like `err.code` might be something like `UNIQUE_VIOLATION` or `ERRCODE_UNIQUE_VIOLATION` too, but not sure about that.