# How to get SQLSTATE in bookshelf.js?

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js

How does one detect the type of an error that occurs in bookshelf.js when talking to PostgreSQL (or another RDBMS)?

Prompted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43815157/398670); I don't use bookshelf.js myself.

A search of the manual did not reveal much that was enlightening.

Comment: Is it `err.sqlState` ?

Comment: isn't it in data?.. ```process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});```

Comment: From my reading of https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg it could be in `err.sqlState` or `err.code`, depending on wether native libpq binding is used or not

Comment: Follow up issue for what @harmic linked: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/938 -- There is also an issue on github about making them standard: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/972 (this latter mentions a way, i.e. `error.code === '42P07' || error.sqlState === '42P07'` to detect errors).